# Javascript slideshow with titles fitting the images

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I made this little Slideshow with HTML/CSS/JS.

Most of it is working but there is one thing which I can't figure out.

How do I make it so the text above each image fits the img itself when autosliding is on?

Right now it only shows the right title for each img when I manually click through.

```js
var uniqueRandoms = [];
var indexCount = 0;
var allImagesAndText = ["Seltene römische Goldmünze", "Römische Funde", "Römische Wandmalerei", "Tutanchamun", "Cheops Pyramide", "Ägyptische Malerei"];
var total = allImagesAndText.length - 1;

function makeUniqueRandom() {
  if (!uniqueRandoms.length) {
    for (var i = indexCount; i <= total; i++) {
      uniqueRandoms.push(i);
    }
  }
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * uniqueRandoms.length);
  var val = uniqueRandoms[index];

  uniqueRandoms.splice(index, 1);

  return val;
}

function slide(x) {
 if(indexCount + x >= 0 && indexCount + x <= total) {
  clearInterval(sliderInterval);
  indexCount += x;
  
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
   Image.src = "images/img" + indexCount + ".jpg";
  
  update_dom();
  

  sliderInterval = window.setInterval( slideA, 3000);
 }
}

function update_dom() {
 var left_holder = document.getElementById('left_holder');
 var right_holder = document.getElementById('right_holder');
 
 ChangeText(indexCount);
 
 if(indexCount == 0) {
  left_holder.style.display =  "none";
 } else if (indexCount == total) {
  right_holder.style.display = "none";
 } else {
  right_holder.style.display = "block";
  left_holder.style.display = "block";
 }
}

function slideA() {
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
  imagescount = makeUniqueRandom();
  Image.src = "images/img" + imagescount + ".jpg";
  update_dom();
}

function ChangeText(imgNum) {
   document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = allImagesAndText[imgNum];
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
 update_dom();
   sliderInterval = window.setInterval( slideA, 3000);
   document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", function() {
    slide(1);
   });
  
   document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click", function() {
    slide(-1);
   });
});
```

```css
#slideshow {
  height: 450px;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#img {
  height: 450px;
  width: 650px;
}
#left_holder {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
#right_holder {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
.left {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0px;
}
.right {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 0px;
}
#text1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  left: 37%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div id="text1">Text</div>
  <img src="images/img0.jpg" id="img" />
  <div id="left_holder">
    <img id="left" class="left" src="images/arrow_left.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="right_holder">
    <img id="right" class="right" src="images/arrow_right.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code does not work at all because you do not currently have any images with ID="img": `var Image = document.getElementById('img');`

Comment: sorry i fixed that now

Comment: indexCount is in slide, imagescount is in slideA - which one do you want to use?

Comment: i want to use imagescount

Comment: So do you want random images or one by one?

Comment: i want random images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
indexCount = imagescount = makeUniqueRandom();
```

instead of

```
 imagescount = makeUniqueRandom();
```